# How to set font-weight bold in html?

Tags: css, text, formatting

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">Bold Text. Normal Text</div>
```

Expected Output:

**Bold Text.** Normal Text

I know to add `<b>` for certain text. But the condition here is not to edit the HTML page. By using CSS or jquery need to set the certain text as bold.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Will the text `Bold Text. Normal Text` remain static? Or will it change?

Comment: No, it is not possible only with CSS.

Comment: @rJ7 You cannot select arbitrary sub-strings with CSS... **Impossible:** adjective, *1. not possible; unable to be, exist, happen, etc.* [See for yourself](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impossible). Oh, and when the question was asked it only mentioned CSS. jQuery was added to the question later.

Comment: @rJ7 He is duplicating the text, putting it in the CSS. What if the text in the HTML changes? It is an incomplete solution, at best.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="test">Bold Text. Normal Text</div>

.test {
    font-size:0;
 }

.test:before {
    font-size: 12px;
    content: "Bold Text. ";
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.test:after {
    font-size: 12px;
    content: "Normal Text";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/td92r3jz/

Fiddle.

Comment: And the reason for the downvote is? 

There's a fiddle link showing that it works.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery.
Get text, split by dot, wrap with `<span>` and put back.
Apply CSS onto first `<span>`. (run the snippet)

```js
var t = $('.test').html().split('.');
var res = '<span>' + t[0] + '.</span><span>' + t[1] + '</span>';

$('.test').html(res);
```

```css
.test>span:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">Bold Text. Normal Text</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could hide the text in your original div with css, and use the :before and :after css-selector to add the text again with css

```
div {
    line-height:1000px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:30px;
}

div:after {
    content:"bold text";
    position:absolute;
    font-weight: bold;
}

div:before {
    content:"normal text";
    position:absolute;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: If I hides the div then  the :after and :before content will not works. It's Wrong.

Comment: But the div isn't hidden. The text is cut off setting the line-height much higher then the actual div, so it should work

Comment: No, I just explained the concept! But here is a working example, so the downvote is wrong! http://jsfiddle.net/2bxat3mv/   I do like the font-size solution more because there is less code, but some browsers have a minimum font-size, so I don't think that's a cross browser solution